# Nestjs CRUD modify response object

Tags: crud, nestjs

I'm currently learning to work with Nestjs and CRUD module. I would like to know what is the bast way to change a response?

This is how response currently looks.

```
[
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

This is how i would like for response to look like.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "key": [
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with using `@nestjsx/crud` in general, but have you looked into adding an `interceptor` globally that has the return looking like this:

```
return next.handle().pipe(map(res => ({ status: 'true', key: res })));
```

This *should* map the value to what you are expecting based on what you've shown.

Comment: This is the similar way that is was doing. I just thought that there is some better solution.                                                                                                             return callHandeler.handle().pipe(map(product => ({ status: true, product })));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Thank you.